# Android - activities approach?

Tags: android, android-activity, nested

I am implementing an aplication, which will have approx 200 activites. I am thinking of two ways of achieving this. First, I really can implement those 200 activities ( I don't know, but I think it will decrease speed of an app on low- or mid- end devices) or I can have 2 activites and dynamicaly swich between them with appropriate data and design.

My questions are - if I take the first way (200 activities), is there any restriction of coming throught activities? Like activity A -> activity B -> ... -> activity G and so far... If I take the other way, is it truely possible to dynamicaly link between activities? (having 2 instead of 200) I have been looking for this for a while and I haven't been able to find any valuable help.

Thanks

Hmyzak

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Although there is no maximum limitation of Activities per application, if you have too many you will run out of memory. If you have many different things to view, consider switching layouts and not activities.

You should ask yourself whether there are really 200 different things you want to offer the user or the are many different layouts that have the same activity behind them.